# Make items in a list unique by appending a letter to duplicates

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers some of which repeat, like below.

```
list = [101,101,102,103,103,103,104,105,106,107,108,108,108,108]
```

When a number repeats in the list I need to append a letter in sequence like 101 would become 101A and 101B and 103A and 103B and 103C. And so on and so forth.

Does anyone Know a way to do this in Python.

I wish to end up with a list like this.

```
list = [101A,101B,102,103A,103B,103C,104,105,106,107,108A,108B,108C,108D]
```

Comment: What have you tried? BTW: this are not valid integers, I'm assuming you are turning them into strings. It is also a very bad idea to use python types as a variable name, e.g. `list`.

Comment: What should happen for an input list like `[100] * 30`?  i.e. where you run out of letters

Comment: Does it matter that the numbers are adjacent in the list?  What output would `[1, 2, 1]` give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools
import string

x = [101,101,102,103,103,103,104,105,106,107,108,108,108,108]
x = list(map(str, x))

def zip_letters(l):
  al = string.ascii_uppercase
  return [''.join(i) for i in zip(l, al)] if len(l) > 1 else l


x = [j for _, i in itertools.groupby(x) for j in zip_letters(list(i)) ]
print(x)
```

Output:

```
['101A', '101B', '102', '103A', '103B', '103C', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108A', '108B', '108C', '108D']
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned there is no defined behaviour for when the letters run out. Also this example does not use ord() or chr():

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

lst1 = [101, 101, 102, 103, 103, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 108, 108, 108]
alphabet = ["", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

NewList = []
dictionary = {}
for i in lst1:
    if i in dictionary:
        dictionary[i] += 1
        letter = alphabet[dictionary[i]]
        NewList.append("{}{}".format(i, letter))
        continue
    else:
        dictionary[i] = 0
        letter = alphabet[dictionary[i]]
        NewList.append("{}{}".format(i, letter))


print(NewList)
```

Which outputs:

```
['101A', '101B', '102A', '103A', '103B', '103C', '104A', '105A', '106A', '107A', '108A', '108B', '108C', '108D']
```

Comment: this does not match the output

Comment: The current requirements will require a look ahead to achieve, which this doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to `itertools.groupby` (assuming only consecutive numbers) then `zip` on the relevant letters (if applicable), e.g.:

```
In []:
import string
l = [101,101,102,103,103,103,104,105,106,107,108,108,108,108]
m = [list(g) for _, g in it.groupby(map(str, l))]
[''.join(x) for g in m for x in zip(g, string.ascii_uppercase if len(g) > 1 else [''])]

Out[]:
['101A', '101B', '102', '103A', '103B', '103C', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108A', '108B', '108C', '108D']
```

The current approach requires you to look ahead to know if there are more than one number to start appending letters. This could be avoided by either having a letter appended to every number or not having a letter on any first occurrence of any number.
Note: both of the following approaches doesn't care about consecutive numbering.

A letter on every number:

```
In []:
d = {}
['{}{}'.format(x, next(d.setdefault(x, iter(string.ascii_uppercase)))) for x in l]

Out[]:
['101A', '101B', '102A', '103A', '103B', '103C', '104A', '105A', '106A', '107A', '108A', '108B', '108C', '108D']
```

Or if you don't mind `['101', '101A', '102', ...]`:

```
In []:
d = {}
letters = [''] + list(string.ascii_uppercase)
['{}{}'.format(x, next(d.setdefault(x, iter(letters)))) for x in l]

Out[]:
['101', '101A', '102', '103', '103A', '103B', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108', '108A', '108B', '108C']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I cam up with.  It's probably not the most performant, and it's a little over complicated, but I thought it was interesting.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from collections import defaultdict

class Maybe_A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_a = False
    def __str__(self):
        return 'A' if self.is_a else ''

def letters():
    a = Maybe_A()
    yield a
    a.is_a = True
    yield from ascii_uppercase[1:]

def tag_duplicates(l):
    d = defaultdict(letters)
    pre_process = [(s, next(d[s])) for s in (str(number) for number in l)]
    return [x+str(y) for x, y in pre_process]

print(tag_duplicates([101,101,102,103,103,103,104,105,106,107,108,108,108,108]))
# ['101A', '101B', '102', '103A', '103B', '103C', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108A', '108B', '108C', '108D']
```